# Gravity forms AJAX not working with WordPress Roots/Sage theme

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

When trying to use AJAX with Gravity Forms 1.9.9 and the Sage WordPress theme, there is the dreaded `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` error and AJAX does not work. How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Sage theme for WordPress, jQuery is registered to load in the footer. Gravity Forms requires that jQuery is loaded in the header, so you just need to make a small change to make sure this happens.

These instructions are for the Sage theme, version 8.2.1

Open `[your_theme_name]/lib/assets.php`, go to line 112 (or locate `wp_register_script('jquery'...` ).

Simply change the final `true` (which specifies that the script should load in the footer to `false` - it should finish up like this:

```
wp_register_script('jquery', bower_map_to_cdn(array(
  'name' => 'jquery',
  'cdn' => 'google',
  'file' => 'jquery.min.js'
), asset_path('scripts/jquery.js')), [], null, false);
```

then jQuery will load in the head and your AJAX should fire up as intended.

Comment: And in case you using Soil - simply remove the add_theme_support(jquery) line from setup.php